# Why the accept() function is still blocking while I call a close on the communication socket?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp, signals

I try to develop a little TCPServer that close properly on a Ctrl-C command. The fact is that even if I close the communication socket at the Ctrl-C command, the accept function is still blocking and the code doesn't not end properly. I don't know why.

I am on a Windows Machine. Coding on a WSL Ubuntu 20.
Compiling with a basic
g++ -set=c++17 -pthread -g main.cpp TCPServer.cpp -o tcpserver

This is the code :

**main.cpp**

```
#include <csignal>
#include "TCPServer.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

bool _isRunning = false;

void signalHandler(int signum){
    _isRunning = false;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    TCPServer tcpserver(20002);

    _isRunning = true;
    std::cout << "Running !" << std::endl;
    while(_isRunning){
        usleep(10);
    }
    std::cout << "Time to Stop !" << std::endl;
    tcpserver.stop();
    tcpserver.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**TCPServer.h**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class TCPServer;

struct thread_params {
    sockaddr_in address;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    int socket;
    unsigned short listeningPort;
    TCPServer * server;
};

class TCPServer {

public:

    TCPServer(unsigned short port);
    ~TCPServer();
    int init();
    int start();
    int stop();
    static int run(TCPServer * server);
    static void startThreadCommunication(thread_params parameters){
        TCPServer *server = parameters.server;
        return server->communicationHandler(parameters);
    }
    inline void join(){
        _runningThread.join();
    }

private:

    // Connection
    unsigned short _connectionPort;
    int _connectionSocket;
    sockaddr_in _address;

    // Thread Management
    static void communicationHandler(thread_params);
    std::vector<std::thread> _comThreads;
    bool _isRunning;
    std::thread _runningThread;
    // Attributes
    unsigned short _nbConnections;
    static unsigned int _idGenerationNb;
};
```

**TCPServer.cpp**

```
#include "TCPServer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <errno.h>

TCPServer::TCPServer(unsigned short port) : 
_connectionPort(port),
_isRunning(false),
_nbConnections(0)
{
    _runningThread = std::thread(TCPServer::run, this);
}

TCPServer::~TCPServer()
{
}

int TCPServer::run(TCPServer * server){

    if(server->init() < 0){
        std::cerr << "TCPServer failed to initialize for previous reasons" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if(server->start() < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "End Run" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int TCPServer::init()
{
    if((_connectionSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0){
        std::cerr << "Socket creation failed : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    _address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    _address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    _address.sin_port = htons(_connectionPort);
    if(bind(_connectionSocket, (sockaddr*) &_address, sizeof(_address)) < 0){
        std::cerr << "Socket binding failed : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void TCPServer::communicationHandler(thread_params threadParameters){
    // Do something for the client
    while(threadParameters.server->_isRunning) {
        usleep(100000);
        
        if(send(threadParameters.socket, "Hi\n", sizeof("Hi\n"), 0) < sizeof("Hi\n")){
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
    send(threadParameters.socket, "Bye\n", sizeof("Bye\n"), 0);
    close(threadParameters.socket);
    return;
}


int TCPServer::start()
{
    std::cout << "ADRESS OF THE SERVER START" << this << std::endl;
    if(listen(_connectionSocket, 6) < 0){
        std::cerr << "Socket listening failed : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    _isRunning = true;
    while (_isRunning){
        usleep(10);
        sockaddr_in newClientAddr;
        int newClientAddrLen = sizeof(newClientAddr);
        int newSocket;
        if((newSocket = accept(_connectionSocket, (sockaddr*)&newClientAddr, (socklen_t*)&newClientAddrLen)) < 0 && _isRunning){
            std::cerr << "Socket accepting failed : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            char ipAddress[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(newClientAddr.sin_addr), ipAddress, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            // Accepting the client
            std::cout << "Client connected" << std::endl;
            thread_params params;
            params.address = newClientAddr;
            params.addrlen = sizeof(newClientAddr);
            params.socket = newSocket;
            params.server = this;
            _comThreads.push_back(std::thread(startThreadCommunication, params));
            // Creating the communication thread
        }
    }
    std::cout << "End start" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int TCPServer::stop(){
    std::cout << "Stop !" << std::endl;
    _isRunning = false;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _comThreads.size(); i++){
        _comThreads[i].join();
    }
    close(_connectionSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

I've already checked the address of the server object and the file descriptor value everything seems great. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Why is the C++ code  tagged with [tag:c]? Read it carefully: *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.*

Comment: Take a look at SO_REUSEADDR

Comment: Don't use `SO_REUSEADDR` as suggested, when it is suggested `SO_REUSEPORT` is assumed. The confusion comes from Windows, that does not have the later one.

Comment: @273K It's not clear which platform they use, IPPROTO_TCP is mandatory in some cases on WIndows only, otherwise protocol can be 0. Actually, depends on version libc you should NOT use `SO_REUSEPORT` with TCP, but only with UDP. In some cases only `SO_REUSEADDR` is available (e.g. you're not using `libc`, or version is low, or kernel version is low) and in some case UDP requires both, but not TCP. `SO_REUSEPORT` is mostly linux\OSX specific.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie *you should NOT use `SO_REUSEPORT` with `TCP`* -- this is wrong information.

Comment: @273K in certain cases. The use of SO_REUSEPORT for QTcpServer in Qt had introduced a very painful bug. If you listen with that option you silently fail. Because only first ever open socket would receive connects.

Comment: The fact that I am coding on a WSL Ubuntu on Windows machine cause the misunderstanding ?

Comment: @Kaldir probably. It's just  IPPROTO_TCP is considered unnecessary and is WIndows programmer's giveaway.  I'd introduce certain level of abstraction here. Oh, and  Windows treats threads and sockets differently, even though WSL "kinda" adapts it.

Comment: Is `accept` supposed to exit when the listening socket is closed out from underneath it? I don't recall any guarantee. Usually I have `accept` inside a `select` or similar with a timeout.

Comment: @user4581301 there was, normally. may require `shutdown()` call. THere is edge case if  connection already happened but was dropped for some reason. It's way more stricter to use `select`